# Running ng build results in Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters

Tags: angular, build, npm-install

Got stuck and need someone's help!

Having issues with building Angular 7 app. Added the following modules to my app:

```
npm install @stomp/stompjs@5.4.4
npm install sockjs-client@1.4.0
```

And now getting the following error when executing ng build as follows:

> [myApp-4.0]$ ng build --prod --base-href=/myApp/ --deploy-url=/myApp/

Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters
Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters
at stringSlice (buffer.js:601:44)
at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:667:10)
at Object.fileBufferToString (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/virtual-fs/host/buffer.js:37:40)
at MapSubscriber._host.read.pipe.operators_1.map.buffer [as project] (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:220:116)
at MapSubscriber._next (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:49:35)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/host.js:172:21)
at Observable._trySubscribe (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
at Observable.subscribe (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
at MapOperator.call (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:32:23)
at Observable.subscribe (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:25:22)
at MapOperator.call (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:32:23)
at Observable.subscribe (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:25:22)
at /my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:22:31
at Object.subscribeToResult (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (/my_app/myApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:82:29)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try increase node memory size node example "--max_old_space_size=4096" , instead of 4096 you can put your prefered size (which support PC), you can check this link too
[link](https://blog.liplex.de/increase-node-memory-limit-for-build/)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried with 4GB and 8GB; still same error. Did this: node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --base-href=/myApp/ --deploy-url=/myApp/

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: somehow my angular.json file became very large (I must've done something by accident). I replaced the file with the correct version and the build worked.

Used this command to find the first 10 largest files under my Angular app directory and its sub-directories. It showed angular.json was the largest file which gave me a "fat" clue:

```
 find . -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -10
```